# can't open mvc c# project in VSE 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csproj

I have project files created with `MVC3, C#, VSE 2010` web developer.
Just installed the latest `VSE 2010` web developer.
When I try to open **.sln** file I got the following message:

```
D:\Work\tech_descr\Site\Site.csproj : error  : The project file 'D:\Work\tech_descr\Site\Site.csproj' cannot be opened.
The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

I checked proposed solutions from forum, but it doesn't work. Looks like my versions of software are fine.
here are strings from **csproj:**

```
<ProjectGuid>{9F99CE4B-6664-401C-AEFD-DD53C3281B42}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Welcomn to [so]. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and what you tried? Please also check out the [faq]'s and [ask] if you haven't already. Good luck!

Comment: Did you install this version?: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=VWDorVS2010SP1Pack - without SP1 and the tooling updates, you don't get support for MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

Dont double click .sln file to open solution,open it form File->Open menu from VSE 2010 it will prompt you to convert

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reinstalling MVC 3.

As an interesting note, those guids are, respectively:

Visual C#

Windows (C#)

Web Application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb23x61k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx